# Fluorescent light wont work after replacing starter and bulb

Tags: fluorescent

I have 2 single bulb fluorescent lights that do not turn on after replacing the bulb and starter.  What else could be preventing the light from turning on?  ANy advice on what should I check? Thanks

Comment: Two things - The BALLAST (most likely) and the Tomb Stones.. (which are the things the fluorescent bulbs plug into. In this situation if the ballast is bad - I replace the unit with an LED fixture and be done with it. Of course for me even if the bulbs were bad (a 24 inch or less unit) - I would not invest in bulbs or starter - that can cost more than a replacement LED unit again I replace rather than repair it. LED unit is cheaper all the way around.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a ballast that can go bad. try turning off the power and removing the starter, then clean the contacts for the bulbs. sometimes there is corrosion or oxide buildup stopping the flow of electricity. However most newer lights no longer have starters it's built into the ballast, So I'm guessing this is an older fixture and that makes the probability of a bad ballast much higher. be aware that the starter can contain high voltages like a capacitor. do not attempt cleaning without removing the starter and turning off the power.

Answer (score 0):

Two things - The BALLAST (most likely) and the Tomb Stones.. (which are the things the fluorescent bulbs plug into. In this situation if the ballast is bad - I replace the unit with an LED fixture and be done with it. Of course for me even if the bulbs were bad (a 24 inch or less unit) - I would not invest in bulbs or starter - that can cost more than a replacement LED unit again I replace rather than repair it. LED unit is cheaper all the way around.